# How to instance hashes to objects (ruby)

Tags: ruby, class, object, methods

I'm currently learning Ruby and I'm on my third day of practicing it but I'm having trouble with classes and objects.

```
escribe Recipe do
it 'Instance an object of type recipe' do
recipe = Recipe.new(title: 'Feijoada',
                    description: 'Você nunca comeu uma receita igual',
                    ingredients: 'Feijão e Carnes',
                    cook_time: 80,
                    featured: true)

expect(recipe.class).to eq Recipe
expect(recipe.title).to eq 'Feijoada'
expect(recipe.description).to eq 'Você nunca comeu uma receita igual'
expect(recipe.ingredients).to eq 'Feijão e Carnes'
expect(recipe.cook_time).to eq 80
expect(recipe.featured).to eq true
end
```

How do I properly initialize every hash in a way that when it returns it will be readable? Running rspec it gives me "NoMethodError: undefined method '-' for nil:NilClass"

This is my current class code:

```
class Recipe
require 'json'
attr_accessor :title, :description, :ingredients, :cook_time, :featured

def initialize(arr)
    @title = arr[:title]
    @description - arr[:description]
    @ingredients = arr[:ingredients]
    @cook_time = arr[:cook_time]
    @featured = arr[:featured]
end

def self.from_json(path)
    arquivo = File.read(path)
    recipe = JSON.parse(arquivo)
end
end
```

Comment: The error message says that you are trying to call the method `-`, but it doesn't exist. There is exactly *one* occurrence of the symbol `-` in your entire code. Look at that occurrence. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem... you put a minus instead of an equals

```
@description - arr[:description]
```

Because instance variables like `@description` are `nil` until initialized, you're trying to run method `-` on a `nil` object, which explains your error message exactly.